# Removal of html tag because HTML questions are off-topic

Tags: discussion, status-declined, tags

I recently had a html question put on hold here and I think I speak for a lot of people when I say although the questions are seen to be put on hold, the fact that there is a tag for [html](https://superuser.com/questions/tagged/html) suggests to me that html questions are supported here.

It causes a lot of confusion. Would it not stop off topic questions regarding html if this tag was removed?

Comment: The nonexistence of a tag never stopped people from posting off-topic questions

Comment: presence/absence of a tag doesn't dictate the offtopic nature of a question

Comment: well it would deter people from asking about html if there was no html tags the point I'm trying to make is not about off topic questions in general its about off topic questions related  to html only I guess I should've said reduce the amount of off topic questions.

Answer (score 3):

I have been speaking to a moderator on the main site and he said that he has changed the description to better direct the questions. That's good enough for me so this question is no longer needed. :)

PS. I wasn't aware that there were legitimate uses for the HTML tag such as configure the editor to handle html files.