# Whats the Context on questions about HTML/JS/CSS

Tags: discussion, support

I have a question about my Super User post: [How do I use .htaccess with offline html?](https://superuser.com/questions/1440757/how-do-i-use-htaccess-with-offline-html)

I'd like to ask why a lot of HTML/JS/CSS based questions are either Denied or Accepted here. Some do have reasons why they should be closed/moderated, but I don't understand the Limits of how far we can ask about HTML/JS/CSS. It seems superuser (as it's description suggests) is a webpage for asking questions about making "shorter/easier/more efficient methods towards solving problems in a way that makes it as the title suggests".

No, I'm not asking for any removal of tags for people who will reference this question: [removal of tag because off-topic](https://meta.superuser.com/questions/7611/removal-of-html-tag-because-html-questions-are-off-topic)

So, in a better basis, say I ask about some Html: **(these are just examples)**

> How do I like a stylesheet to my html page?

This question seems like it would fit better in Stackoverflow because its specifically defining to ask about General HTML code-help.
But are questions like the ones below off-topic?:

> Is it possible to write other HTML versions in the same page?
>   
>   How do I change my HTML version, and what determines it?

Im asking because im generally unsure about how to use these tags: (html) (css) (javascript)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Questions about programming related to HTML/CSS/etc are off-topic, as are almost all other programming questions (with the notable exception of scripting languages: batch/vbs/powershell/bash/etc).

Questions about software that facilitate programming and development (webservers/deamons/IDEs/compilers/etc) are on-topic - just like questions about any other software.

Your [question](https://superuser.com/questions/1440757/how-do-i-use-htaccess-with-offline-html) is on-topic, since it's not about programming and the answer is to install webserver software.

Please take a look at [this](https://superuser.com/help/on-topic) page to learn what is on-topic and what isn't.

Neither of the following questions are on-topic on Super User:

> 1. Is it possible to write other HTML versions in the same page?
> 2. How do I change my HTML version, and what determines it?

They are about programming, not software or hardware. Please ask on Stack Overflow instead, after checking and making sure no duplicates exist. Also, don't ask if a simple web search answers the question.

Comment: so Html, Css, and Js tags are only available for use, when say we use questions on webserver software/hardware? Its unfortunate its the same tag as an HTML question in stackoverflow, perhaps a moderator/staff should consider renaming the tags.

Comment: @TaylorSpark I think you don't know enough about web dev yet, but you will soon learn that the programming language used on webpages is largely irrelevant when it comes to webservers serving files. The HTML tag exists mostly for questions related to rendering of HTML in web browsers and similar - which are on-topic since they're about software, not programming.

Comment: Ah, Okay I see now, thankyou for the input. also what I mean by "so Html, Css, and Js tags are only available for use, when say we use questions on webserver software/hardware" is so when people ask questions about their html inside of their website/webserver. Either way, I guess thats still off-topic.

Comment: @TaylorSpark if it's a question about webservers serving files (which are very much on-topic), the fact that the pages were written in HTML is irrelevant, and therefore `html` would be an inappropriate tag for the question, and should not be added.   

Tags must be relevant to the _problem_ being discussed, not every aspect of the situation.

Comment: Should tags such as html, css and js be burninated then? If there is a direct need for them, they could be replaced with a more suitable name.

Comment: @TaylorSpark Please see my previous comment. These tags are relevant when being discussed in the context of web browsers.

Comment: Im sorry if my confusion can be infuriating as some have said. Perhaps you can link me to an example question that correctly uses the HTML, CSS, or Javascript tags?

Comment: Rather than considering technologies, it's probably easier to consider use cases. If you're asking questions involving code, SO is better. If you're asking questions about the tools for writing these things or end user issues we are on topic

Comment: @TaylorSpark the `html` tag would be appropriate for [this](https://superuser.com/questions/414198/get-current-html-of-page-built-with-ajax-requests/1307393#1307393) on-topic question. `javascript`, `html` and `css` tags are often appropriately used with [tag:bookmarklet], although there are other cases where they should/can be used too.